# any item from set matches any from another

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to define something like nameFilters and then check from a list of given strings if any of the nameFilters fits string so some kind of pseudo code would look like:

```
if any from filters in strings:
    #do the job
```

Where filter is in fact just a substring that we want to find in a string.

Of course it can be done the hard way:

```
for filter in filters:
    for string in strings:
        if filter in string:
            # do the job
```

But it is not readable and has lots of nesting. Python generally is a language where you can do things in a extremally readable way, but I could not find one for this particular problem.

Comment: `if any(filter in string for filter, string in itertools.product(filters, strings)):`?

Comment: Are you looking for substrings within the list of string (as your code suggests) or exact matches in the list of strings?

Comment: I am looking for substrings in the list of strings. I have list of strings(filters) and list of strings to check. If any from the list of filter is in any of strings to check I want it to return true.

Comment: `if any(any(substring in instring for substring in filters) for instring in strings):` also works, not sure there's a clear choice between that or the `iterools.product` version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it appears you are trying to filter a list of strings by a list of filters ... a string matches if any filter matches any part of the string

```
 matches = [s for s in strings if any(f in s for f in filters))]
```

but im not sure thats alot more readable than your other solution its just in one line ...

if you wanted to do something with them you could change it to an iteratator comprehension instead of a list comprehension, that way you would only evaluate it one time

```
matches = (s for s in strings if any(f in s for f in filters)))
for m in matches:
    do_something(m)
```

Comment: This is basically fine, but if you're really only interested in the boolean value this has the down side of not short-circuiting as soon as a match is found. `any_matches = any(s for s in strings if any(f in s for f in filters))` is yet another way to express the short-circuiting version - I hope the parallelism to the list comprehension version is clear.